# "Javascript - The Definitive Guide" - Uncaught TypeError: trace(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying the examples in "Javascript - The Definitive Guide" Chapter 8 Functions.  In Section 8.3.4 "The Spread Operator for Function Calls", the code was workable:

```
function timed(f) {
  return function(...args) {
    console.log(`Entering function ${f.name}`);
    let startTime = Date.now();
    try {
      return f(...args);
    }
    finally {
      console.log(`Exiting ${f.name} after
        ${Date.now()-startTime}ms`);
    }
  };
}
function benchmark(n) {
  let sum = 0;
  for(let i = 1; i <= n; i++) sum += i;
  return sum;
}
timed(benchmark)(1000000);
```

The console output is:

```
Entering function benchmark
Exiting benchmark after 46ms
```

In Section 8.7.4 "The call() and apply() Methods", the function timed() was changed to trace() and I could not get the code to work:

```
function trace(o, m) {
 let original = o[m];
 o[m] = function(...args) {
   console.log(new Date(), "Entering:", m);
   let result = original.apply(this, args);
   console.log(new Date(), "Exiting:", m);
   return result;
 };
}
trace(benchmark)(1000000);
```

This error is thrown:

Uncaught TypeError: trace(...) is not a function

I've tried a few variants, but all did not work:

```
benchmark.trace(1000000);
trace.benchmark(1000000);
benchmark.call(trace, 1000000);
obj = {};
trace(obj, benchmark(1000000));
```

I did a check with this:

```
console.log(typeof trace);
```

The output indicates that trace() is a function...

Could someone please explain how trace() should be used with benchmark()?  Do I need to create new objects or functions?

The book only provided this Hint:

> The trace() function defined in the following is similar to the timed() function defined in §8.3.4, but it works for methods instead of functions. It uses the apply() method instead of a spread operator, and by doing that, it is able to invoke the wrapped method with the same arguments and the same this value as the wrapper method:

```
// Replace the method named m of the object o with a version that logs
// messages before and after invoking the original method.
function trace(o, m) { ...
```

Comment: `function trace` does not `return` anything, so `trace(...)(...)` won't ever work.

Comment: The way you call `trace(benchmark)(1000000);` your `trace` function is supposed to return a function, but it does not return anything ... So if you got that code from a book, you probably missed something

Comment: Furthermore, `function trace(o, m)` indicates it expects two arguments, but you call it as `trace(benchmark)` - only one argument passed.

Comment: Rather than copying code blindly from a book, you should seek to understand what the code you are typing is doing. Otherwise you are not a programmer, you are a [paster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-and-paste_programming).

Comment: And furthermore, you should read the error messages more carefully. Yes `trace` is a function. But the error you are seeing is complaing about `trace(...)` (ie the result of `trace(...)`) not being a function.

Comment: @derpirscher, I've included a Hint from the book in my updated post.  I'm still unable to comprehend how the function works...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, I also tried this:  `obj = {};
    trace(obj, benchmark(1000000));` But nothing showed up in the Console of my Chrome browser...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the updated method `trace` is supposed to take an object (`o`) and a method on that object (`m`) and it is designed to kind of decorate that method with benchmarking functionality.

Here's how to use it:

```js
function trace(o, m) {
 let original = o[m];
 o[m] = function(...args) {
   console.log(new Date(), "Entering:", m);
   let result = original.apply(this, args);
   console.log(new Date(), "Exiting:", m);
   return result;
 };
}

const myObject = {
   benchmark: function(n){
      let sum = 0;
      for(let i = 1; i <= n; i++) sum += i;
      return sum;
   }
}

// set up the trace "decorator" so that the method is traced
trace(myObject,"benchmark");

// now call the method and see the trace output
myObject.benchmark(1000000);
```

We can break down further how this works

```
let original = o[m];
```

When you pass in an object and a method name, the above line captures a local variable with a pointer to that function

```
o[m] = function(...args) {
   ....
}
```

The part above *replaces* that function on the object with a pointer to a new function

```
let result = original.apply(this, args);
```

The line above calls the original function ([using `apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)) with the arguments passed in. You'll note that is is topped and tailed with the `console.log` which you're using to see when the method is entered and exited. Finally the newly attached method returns the result of calling the `original` method.

Comment: Thanks, I've also tried this: `obj = {}; benchmark.call(obj); trace(obj, benchmark); obj.benchmark(1000000);`.  This leads to: `Uncaught TypeError: obj.benchmark is not a function`.  I'm wondering why we can't just simply associate the existing `benchmark` function to a new `obj` object using `call`, and then use `trace(obj, benchmark)` and `obj.benchmark(1000000)`?

Comment: @maxloo you can. `obj = {}; obj.benchmark=benchmark; trace(obj,"benchmark"); obj.benchmark(10000);` - the `trace` method needs to be called with a string as the second parameter as that is how it is defined to work!

Comment: Thanks, using `obj.benchmark = benchmark;` with `trace(obj, "benchmark");` works.  Is there any reason why both `benchmark.call(obj);` and `benchmark.apply(obj);` don't work?  Those lead to: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apply') at Object.o.<computed> [as benchmark]`.  This error happens at `let result = original.apply(this, args);` because it was indicated by the error line number in the Console.

Comment: @maxloo well, they dont work just because the code isnt designed to work that way. Not much more to really say

Answer (score 0):

Importantly, the code example is using function expression syntax and not arrow function expression syntax. This would not work if you are using arrow functions and the original function uses the "this" keyword because the value of this will take on lexical scoping and represent the value of this from the outer scope, which in this example in strict mode will be undefined and in non-strict mode would be the global object.

By using the function expression syntax with the function keyword, the value of this is the receiver, in this case myObject. Now, apply is perfectly fine with taking an undefined value as its first argument. In this example, it woudln't matter since the original function doesn't use the this keyword, but if it did, you could potentially get an error when using it or unexpected results:

```
function trace(o, m) {
   let original = o[m];
   o[m] = (...args) => {
     console.log(new Date(), "Entering:", m);
     let result = original.apply(this, args);
     console.log(new Date(), "Exiting:", m);
     return result;
   };
  }
  
  const myObject = {
     a: 1,
     benchmark: (n) => {
        let sum = 0 + this.a;
        for(let i = 1; i <= n; i++) sum += i;
        return sum;
     }
  }
  
  trace(myObject,"benchmark");
  myObject.benchmark(1000000);

2023-04-27T17:01:01.575Z Entering: benchmark
2023-04-27T17:01:01.581Z Exiting: benchmark
NaN
```